# Como utilizar diferentes arquivos .kv em uma aplicação com Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Estou tentando criar um jogo usando Kivy na linguagem Python e eu gostaria de saber como posso usar diferentes arquivos `.kv` para serem utilizados na aplicação como fases para o jogo. Exemplo:

```
main.py
game.kv
fases/
   fase1.kv
   fase2.kv
   fase3.kv
   ...
```

É possível dividir o meu arquivo `.kv` em diversos outros como no exemplo acima ? Se sim, como posso fazê-lo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível sim.

No código Python, lembre-se de carregar os arquivos usando o Builder:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('caminho_para_arquivo_kivy.kv')
```

No arquivo kv principal (main.kv), você pode importar outros arquivos kv.

```
<main_kv>: 

    cols: 1

    AnchorLayout: 
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'center'

        OutroKv: 
            size_hint: [None, None] 
            size: [app.x, app.y]
```

No outro arquivo Kv:

```
<OutroKv@BoxLayout>: 
    Button: 
        text: 'Outro KV'
```

Dessa forma você consegue modular melhor a interface gráfica da sua aplicação.

Comment: Você pode adicionar no final da resposta um pequeno exemplo de como ficaria o arquivo `.py` e o arquivo `.kv` por favor ?

Answer (score 5):

Pela sua necessidade aparenta que você precisa não só carregar a proxima fase, mas também encerrar/descarregar a anterior, pois acaso não o faça isso irá ficar ocupando memória no seu projeto, então para resolver isto como eu disse no chat no dia 29/01:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11910?m=53387019#53387019

> Entendo pouco disto, mas pelo que entendo não basta "carregar" com Builder.load_file e "descarregar" com Builder.unload_file e claro, depois de descarregar execute no "widget" que está carregando o widget.clear_widgets()? Claro que provavelmente pode haver uma ou outra coisa, como "eventos", mas ai é só planejar bem o código para remover na hora certa

Eu não formulei a resposta porque não tinha tido tempo de fazer o downgrade do Python3.8 para o 3.7 (o kivy ainda não tem suporte para o 3.8), agora feito os testes irei formalizar a resposta, no exemplo `self.palco` se refere ai Layout principal do aplicativo, supondo que a `fase1` já esteja carregado e você queira carregar a `fase2` deve ficar assim:

```
# Remove a fase antiga
self.palco.clear_widgets()

# carrega e adiciona a fase2
self.palco.add_widget(Builder.load_file('fases/fase2.kv'))

# DESCARREGA e a fase1 (que já foi removida com o clear_widgets)
Builder.unload_file('fases/fase1.kv')
```

Então basicamente tivemos que usar:

- [**`add_widget`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout.add_widget) para adicionar a próxima fase
- [**`remove_widget`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout.remove_widget) remove a próxima fase que não está mais em uso
- [**`clear_widgets`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets) remove a fase do layout
- [**`Builder.load_file`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.load_file) carrega a fase
- [**`Builder.unload_file`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.unload_file) descarrega a fase que não está mais em uso

Para testar criei o seguinte exemplo:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class GameApp(App):
    palco = None
    fase_atual = 1
    total_fases = 3


    def run(self):
        super().run()


    def on_start(self):
        self.palco = self.root.ids['palco']
        self.palco.add_widget(Builder.load_file(f'fases/fase{self.fase_atual}.kv'))


    def alerta(self, texto):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)
        popup = Popup(title='Jogo', auto_dismiss=False, content=layout)

        label = Label(text=texto)
        layout.add_widget(label)

        fechar = Button(text="Continuar")
        fechar.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
        layout.add_widget(fechar)

        popup.open()


    def carregar_fase(self, novo):
        print('Removendo fases')

        self.palco.clear_widgets()

        print(f'Carrengado o fase {novo}')

        self.palco.add_widget(Builder.load_file(f'fases/fase{novo}.kv'))

        anterior = self.fase_atual

        self.fase_atual = novo

        print(f'Decarrengado o fase {anterior}')

        Builder.unload_file(f'fases/fase{anterior}.kv')


    def voltar_fase(self):
        proximo = self.fase_atual - 1

        if proximo < 1:
            self.alerta('Não há fases anteriores')
        else:
            self.carregar_fase(proximo)


    def proxima_fase(self):
        proximo = self.fase_atual + 1

        if proximo > self.total_fases:
            self.alerta('Não há próximas fases')
        else:
            self.carregar_fase(proximo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

E no `game.kv` adicionei:

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        id: palco
    Button:
        text: "Fase anterior"
        on_release:
            app.voltar_fase()
    Button:
        text: "Próximo fase"
        on_release:
            app.proxima_fase()
```

No exemplo o `GridLayout` é o layout do programa todo, botões e fase atual do jogo, os "botões" (<kbd>Fase anterior</kbd> e <kbd>Próximo mapa</kbd>) que são apenas para testar os mapas. Já o `BoxLayout` deve receber os widgets que representam a fase atual, ele é o "palco".

A janela de alerta, `def alerta(self, texto)`, não influencia no funcionamento, ela é meramente para entender em que houve um problema ao tentar acessar uma fase fora do "range" (no exemplo o range é de 3 fases).

Um detalhe importante, para usar a propriedade "nativa do kivy" chamada `self.root.ids` é preciso esperar a tela carregar os componentes principais relacionados ao `App`, logo o `self.root.ids` **não irá funcionar** se usado nos métodos:

- `def __init__`
- `def build`
- `def run` (substituição na herança)

Por isto usei o `def on_load(self)`, assim é possível obter os ids e no caso do exemplo o "palco" (`BoxLayout`) para receber as fases.

Comment: Foi muito bem explicado Guilherme muito obrigado por tudo! Acabei percebendo que naquele código que eu tinha feito de exemplo, ele estava dando um erro pois no arquivo .kv eu definia o nome do widget com "<>" dessa forma: `<MyWidget>`. Ao ver esse seu código e retirar o sinal maior e menor ele funcionou. Sabe o porquê ? Mais uma vez obrigado pela paciência e esforço em me ajudar S2

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 vale uma pergunta sobre o assunto. PS: só pra lhe adiantar, sem <> seria para uma instância especifica no seu caso o "app"... já com <> serviria para qualquer instância, seria como um "padrão", que pode ser de aparência e eventos, se entendi direito: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#rule-context